# How to run a ReactApp in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, tomcat, reactjs

I'm able to run any ReactApp only on Nodejs server, but not on a Tomcat server.

Some Qs:

1. React is purely client side rendered library, and why it requires Nodejs (which is server based)? Why React official Tut recommends Nodejs?
2. Is it true that Tomcat is for running pure Java applications, and Nodejs for pure JavaScript applications?

---

I tried to run a sample ReactApplication with few containers in Apache Tomcat, by including the Reactjs include files. But, I get a blank screen. Inspect element shows the non rendered JS source.

**Update 1:**

If yes for Q1, then [Here's](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate) a simple React ready application (with all dependencies included) which is easy to run in Nodejs using NPM. How can I run the same app in Tomcat? Can I able to create Web ARchive using this?

Comment: Hi All,I am too looking for the same answers. How to run a react app on tomcat/how to create a war file of a react app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.React is purely client side rendered library, and why it requires Nodejs (which is server based)? Why React official Tut recommends Nodejs?

React is a client-side library but it requires NodeJs for below reasons : 
 - React uses JSX syntax which browsers doesn't understand and hence it needs to convert into a javascript code that browsers can understand, Babel will do that. Babel needs NodeJs and with the configuration you can convert JSX, ES6 code into ES 5 which browsers can understand 
 - You may also need node js server if you are using React on server side but this is optional

The sample that you have given needs to transpile into ES 5 code using web-pack which uses Babel. WebPack and Babel both need node js. Hence you need NodeJs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you hide under ReactApp.

1. But if you use React in client Side you don't need Nodejs server to run it. You can you Nodejs to build it, there is tools to simplify the work. So your ReactApp will be only an HTML page with some js dependencies. Apache or Tomcat can serve it, but for Tomcat you have to bundle it as WAR I think.
   But you need rest endpoint to do some stuff, and you can do that with lot of technologies include java and tomcat.
2. YES

Comment: I do an application with java and React in Google App Engine https://onlinetallycounter.capverszero.fr/ (so It's a free account my instance is very slow because it go in hibernation most of the time).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [Here's](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate) a simple React ready application (with all dependencies included) which is easy to run in Nodejs using NPM. How can I run the same app in Tomcat? Can I able to create Web ARchive using this?

Comment: I don't know that project but it's to develop it generate bundle.js for take the last changes. In production mode I think you can get bundle.js and link it to your html page.

Comment: Yes, the bundle.js is created after processing the data to ES5  using babel transpiler, and then presented on the index. Just `npm run start` does the trick for Node.js. @Dhananjaya Kuppu cleared the rest, why it can't run in Tomcat. Thanks!